# Proper build options for deploying app that uses external lib

Tags: c++, linker, codeblocks

I'm trying to make a small C++ program that retreives a webpage and makes some manipulations. I want `cURL` to get the content of my site. I downloaded [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=lib&os=Win32&flav=-).

My IDE is Code::Blocks.
I've added the following parameters to my project build options:

[image]

It runs well, but only in IDE. When I try to run my executable from explorer.exe, I get a message saying that I cannot run programm because of missing `libcurl.dll`. How to resolve this?

My compiler is MinGW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation of this is that the tool used by C::B to run your program in the IDE,
`cb_console_runner.exe`, "helpfully" adds the linker search directories specified in your
project to the runtime DLL search order.

So, because you have specified `curl-windows\bin` as a linker search directory, 
and that is where `libcurl.dll` is, your program finds it when run by `cb_console_runner.exe`.
But since `curl-windows\bin` is not in *Windows* DLL search order, the DLL is not found
when you run your executable directly.

To verify this:-

- Build your project successfully
- Run it successfully in the IDE
- Temporarily delete `curl-windows\bin` from the Linker search directories
- Run from the IDE again, without rebuilding.

On the second run, you will get the missing `libcurl.dll` error.

To be able to run your program directly `libcurl.dll` must be found in
the [Windows DLL search order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx).

BTW, it is pointless for you to link both `libcurl.a` and `libcurldll.a`.
If you are going to use the DLL, don't link `libcurl.a`.

In fact, as long as you are linking `libcurldll.a`, specifying `curl-windows\bin` as a 
linker search directory is pointless, as nothing you need *at buildtime* is there, and its presence
only serves to cause the *runtime* confusion that your question is about.

Answer (score 1):

You need to distribute (deploy) the cURL dll together with your executable program, or you have to make somehow sure that Windows will find that dll in the dll search path. Normally, the directory where the excutable is found and the current directory are part of the dll search path. This is independent of your development environment and/or compiler.
Welcome to the DLL hell!

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it doesn't run on *my* machine.